# Fade-In with transition via CSS/jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, fadein

I am stumbling in an attempt to add a fade-in transition to the following code. The code is from this [blog](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/how-to-create-a-circular-icon-menu-that-expands-on-click-in-divi) and as you can see, creates a clickable menu item that expands on click. I have no problem getting the code to work as the author intended. However, I want to use custom graphics as my base image and submenus, but in doing so I can't hide the submenus behind the base menu. I thought it would be fairly simple to introduce a fade-in (either/or CSS & jquery) transition to his existing code so that initially the submenus are invisible (opacity: 0) then fade in on click. As you can surmise, I've failed at the attempt.

How could these snippets be written so the class **.et-pb-icon** would initially be hidden and achieve 100% opacity when the transition completes?

Thanks.

```
       <style>
          .has-transform, .transform_target .et-pb-icon {
            transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
          } 
          .toggle-transform-animation {
            transform: none !important;
          }
          .transform_target {
            cursor: pointer;
          }
          .toggle-active-target.et_pb_blurb .et-pb-icon {
          background-color: transparent;
          }
       </style>

       <script>
          (function($) {
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $('.transform_target').click(function(){
                $(this).toggleClass('toggle-active-target');
                $('.has-transform').toggleClass('toggle-transform-animation');   
              });    
            });
          })( jQuery );   
          </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% without the HTML section but could you not do something like

```
.et-pb-icon {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
} 

.has-transform, .transform_target .et-pb-icon {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, I couldn't get the code to work. This is what has me flummoxed. The moment I add **opacity: 1;** anywhere in that snippet they targets remain visible throughout. I suppose I could hide the targets off page, but that method seems inelegant to me.

Comment: Try this so you're not adding opacity to the parent instead just adding it to the child element that you trying to target `.et-pb-icon {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
} 

.has-transform .transform_target .et-pb-icon {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}

.has-transform{
    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
}`

Comment: -- Thanks again for the reply, Dan. Sorry so slow on the response. I was finally able to construct the correct snippet. I was making it out to be more difficult that it was.  See above.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

Finally figured out the correct code.
(I used **.et_pb_module_header** in place of **.et_pb_module_icon** secondary to using only text for keywords).

```
<style>
  .has-transform, .transform_target .et_pb_module_header {
    transition: all 400ms ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;
  } 
  .toggle-transform-animation {
    transform: none !important;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .transform_target {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .toggle-active-target.et_pb_blurb .et_pb_module_header {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
</style>
```